# How to reverse a dictionary (whose values are lists) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to write a function that receives a dictionary as input argument and returns a reverse of the input dictionary where the values of the original dictionary are used as keys for the returned dictionary and the keys of the original dictionary are used as value for the returned dictionary as explained below:

```
dict = {'Accurate': ['exact', 'precise'], 
        'exact': ['precise'], 
        'astute': ['Smart', 'clever'], 
        'smart': ['clever', 'bright', 'talented']}
```

to

```
dict = {'precise': ['accurate', 'exact'], 
        'clever': ['astute', 'smart'], 
        'talented': ['smart'], 
        'bright': ['smart'],
        'exact': ['accurate'],
        'smart': ['astute']}
```

The list of values in the returned dictionary should be sorted in ascending order.  Capitalization does not matter. This means that all the words should be converted to lower case letters. For example the word "Accurate" is capitalized in the original dictionary but in the returned dictionary it is written with all lower case letters.

```
#My code is:
from collections import defaultdict
def reverse_dictionary(input_dict):
   d = defaultdict(list)
   for v,k in input_dict.items():
       d[k].append(v)
       return d
```

But it returns this error though:

```
Error in evaluating function:
TypeError at line 6
unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use any object as a key -- these objects must be immutable so their hash value does not change after they're added to the dictionary. In your case, lists are mutable, so they cannot be used as keys. You could convert them to tuples instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It might be helpful to give more thought to this problem. For example, why would `'Accurate': ['exact', 'precise']` become `'precise': ['accurate', 'exact']` instead of `'exact': ['accurate', 'precise']`?

As far as your error message is concerned, a list cannot be your dict key, but I think the bigger problem is that you task needs to be clarified.

Comment: Also, dictionaries cannot be sorted.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi He is *trying* to use strings as keys, not lists.  He just isn't doing it right.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. The content of the values become the keys, and the keys get added to the values, so `{'a': ['b', 'c']}` becomes `{'b': ['a'], 'c': ['a']}`. @DanielStandage, @SteinarLima

Comment: AH, I get it @DanielStandage - like I said, I can be a bit slow from time to time.. Hehe :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it very simply like this:

```
newdict = {}
for key, value in olddict.items():
    for string in value:
        newdict.setdefault(string, []).append(key)
```

Comment: Always, always, always use dict comprehensions when the chance arises :)

Comment: Can you give an example?  I just couldn't think of one that would work.

Comment: Oh, oops - I thought that's what you'd done, I was being dumb. I wasn't trying to be condescending but I realize that's exactly how I came off, apologies

Comment: Nuts.  I was hoping you could come up with one ;)  I took out the list comprehension because it really shouldn't be used.

Comment: I still appreciated it nonetheless :)

Answer (score 5):

I would begin by swapping the keys/values using a default dict:

```
output_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in input_dict.items():
    for value in values:
        output_dict[value.lower()].append(key.lower())
```

And finally sorting:

```
for key, values in output_dict.items():
    output_dict[key] = sorted(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict comprehension!

```
>>> evil_petting_zoo = {'bear':3, 'crocodile':1,'kangaroo':2,'goat':0}
>>> evil_petting_zoo.items()

dict_items([('bear', 3), ('crocodile', 1), ('kangaroo', 2), ('goat', 0)])

>>> {i[1]:i[0] for i in evil_petting_zoo.items()}

{3: 'bear', 1: 'crocodile', 2: 'kangaroo', 0: 'goat'}
```

TL;DR:

```
{i[1]:i[0] for i in myDictionary.items()}
```

Comment: That's not what the question asked. It asks for the case when the value is a list.

Answer (score 1):

For the love of functional programming, here’s fun way:

```
from itertools import product
from more_itertools import map_reduce, flatten

olddict =  {'Accurate': ['exact', 'precise'], 
        'exact': ['precise'], 
        'astute': ['Smart', 'clever'], 
        'smart': ['clever', 'bright', 'talented']}

value_key_pairs = flatten(product(v,(k,)) for k,v in olddict.items())
out = map_reduce(value_key_pairs, lambda k:k[0].lower(), lambda k:k[1].lower())

assert dict(out) == {'exact': ['accurate'], 'precise': ['accurate', 'exact'], 'smart': ['astute'], 'clever': ['astute', 'smart'], 'bright': ['smart'], 'talented': ['smart']}
```

Answer (score -2):

How I reverse a dict:

```
def reverse(org):
    return {v: k for k, v in org.items()}

print(reverse({1: 'a', 2: 'b'}))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: this answer is best suited to my problem (and for a standard key:value dict). Thanks ;)

Comment: This doesn't work if the dictionary values are lists (as in the question).