# pythonic way to reverse a dict where values are lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
letters_by_number = {
  1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  2: ['b', 'd'],
  3: ['a', 'c'],
  4: ['a', 'd'],
  5: ['b', 'c']
}
```

I want to reverse it to look something like this:

```
numbers_by_letter = {
  'a': [1, 3, 4],
  'b': [1, 2, 5],
  'c': [1, 3, 5],
  'd': [1, 2, 4]
}
```

I know that I could do this by looping through (key, value) through `letters_by_number`, looping through `value` (which is a list), and adding (val, key) to a list in the dictionary. This is cumbersome and I feel like there must be a more "pythonic" way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverting a dictionary with list values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491223/inverting-a-dictionary-with-list-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse a dictionary (whose values are lists) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945473/how-to-reverse-a-dictionary-whose-values-are-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is well-suited for [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> numbers_by_letter = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, seq in letters_by_number.items():
...     for letter in seq:
...         numbers_by_letter[letter].append(k)
... 
>>> dict(numbers_by_letter)
{'a': [1, 3, 4], 'b': [1, 2, 5], 'c': [1, 3, 5], 'd': [1, 2, 4]}
```

Note that you don't really need the final `dict()` call (a `defaultdict` will already give you the behavior you probably want), but I included it here because the result from your question is type `dict`.

Comment: The result is actually: `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 3, 4], 'c': [1, 3, 5], 'b': [1, 2, 5], 'd': [1, 2, 4]})` since `numbers_by_letter` is a `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
letters_by_number = {
    1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    2: ['b', 'd'],
    3: ['a', 'c'],
    4: ['a', 'd'],
    5: ['b', 'c']
}

inv = {}
for k, vs in letters_by_number.items():
    for v in vs:
        inv.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

print(inv)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': [1, 3, 4], 'b': [1, 2, 5], 'c': [1, 3, 5], 'd': [1, 2, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A (trivial) subclass of `dict` would make this very easy:

```
class ListDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = []
        return value


letters_by_number = {
  1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  2: ['b', 'd'],
  3: ['a', 'c'],
  4: ['a', 'd'],
  5: ['b', 'c']
}


numbers_by_letter = ListDict()
for key, values in letters_by_number.items():
    for value in values:
        numbers_by_letter[value].append(key)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(numbers_by_letter, width=40)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 3, 4],
 'b': [1, 2, 5],
 'c': [1, 3, 5],
 'd': [1, 2, 4]}
```

Comment: Seems like this is exactly what the `collections.defaultdict` class does! The more you know!

Comment: @jxmorris12: To a large degree it accomplishes the same thing, but one difference is that it does not define its own `__repr__()` or `__str__()` methods, so instances typically look exactly like regular dictionaries when displayed. Another possible advantage is that, depending on what you plan on doing with the result, the `__missing__()` method can be made to do other, non-trivial things.

Comment: @martineau Shouldn't it have a different `__repr__` though since it's a subclass? Something like `ListDict({'a': [1, 3, 4], ...})`

Comment: @wjandrea: Yes, technically — according to the docs — it _should_ so the returned string could be used to recreate the object. However if you define one then it will also be used as the `__str__()` method unless you also define that. This quickly makes the class not-so-trivial which sorta defeats its primary purpose (expediency).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a dict comprehension, without adding list elements in a loop. Build a set of keys by joining all the lists together, then build each list using a list comprehension. To be more efficient, I've first built another dictionary containing sets instead of lists, so that `k in v` is an O(1) operation.

```py
from itertools import chain

def invert_dict_of_lists(d):
    d = { i: set(v) for i, v in d.items() }
    return {
        k: [ i for i, v in d.items() if k in v ]
        for k in set(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
    }
```

Strictly, dictionaries in modern versions of Python 3 retain the order that keys are inserted in. This produces a result where the keys are in the order they appear in the lists; not alphabetical order like in your example. If you do want the keys in sorted order, change `for k in set(...)` to `for k in sorted(set(...))`.

Comment: Personally, I think there is nothing un-Pythonic about using a loop instead of a comprehension. Brad's answer is cleaner and easier to understand, and should be at least as efficient too; his way is how I would solve the problem myself. I've posted this answer anyway, because the question implies that you want to do it without a loop.