# Efficient way to get from {key1: [value1, value2...]} to {value1: [key1, key2...]}

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary like this:

```
animals_dict = 
{'cat': ['black', 'white', 'orange'],
'dog': ['black', 'white'],
'parrot': ['orange', 'green']}
```

And I want to get this:

```
colors_dict = 
{'black': ['cat', 'dog'],
'white': ['cat', 'dog'],
'orange': ['cat', 'parrot'],
'green': ['parrot']}
```

The obvious way is to cycle through each animal in animals_dict; cycle through each of its colors; and add the animal to that color in colors_dict. But if you have tens of millions of animals and each animal can have up to a hundred colors, this will get computationally expensive. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Not really. You could possibly convert your dict to a `pandas` `DataFrame` and transpose the resulting dataframe, but the performance gain there comes from doing those calculations outside python rather than from a more efficient approach

Comment: No; you have a graph with a billion edges, and each of them needs to be reversed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/reverse-invert-a-dictionary-mapping
Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Bacteria - Those answers only work for one-to-one mappings or are the trivial solution mentioned in the question.

Comment: How many unique colors exist? Maybe convert them to numbers will speed up the computation.

Comment: @AndrejKesely There are millions of unique colors, though each animal will only have a small subset.

Comment: The values don't matter; it's the number of pairs induced by number of animals and colors that makes this slow.

Comment: Where did you get the dictionary in the first place? Can you generate the two unidirectional mappings at the same time?

Comment: What's the average number of colors for each animal?

Comment: @KellyBundy Probably in the low two figures, but there's a lot of variation -- some have hundreds.

Answer (score 3):

```
index = {'cat': ['black', 'white', 'orange'],'dog': ['black', 'white'],'parrot': ['orange', 'green']}

new_dic = {}
for k,v in index.items():
    for x in v:
        new_dic.setdefault(x,[]).append(k)
print(new_dic)
```

This gives

```
{
    'black': ['cat', 'dog'], 
    'white': ['cat', 'dog'], 
    'orange': ['cat', 'parrot'], 
    'green': ['parrot']
}
```

[pythonic way to reverse a dict where values are lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863255/pythonic-way-to-reverse-a-dict-where-values-are-lists) / [How to reverse a dictionary (whose values are lists) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945473/how-to-reverse-a-dictionary-whose-values-are-lists-in-python)

Comment: Yes, this is the obvious way the OP mentioned.

Comment: Ok, yes, so it is

Comment: The answer to OP's question (_"Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?"_) is _no!_ Copying the approach from an existing question that OP has specifically rejected on account of being too slow is not a good answer. I'm surprised this is getting upvotes.

Comment: Moreover, if you believe this question is answered elsewhere, then the correct action is to vote/flag as duplicate (if you have those [privileges](/help/privileges))

Comment: Are you single?