# Retrieving key for a given value from a dict composed of multiple arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a dictionary composed of arrays of unequal length that looks like the following:

```
mydict = {'A': array([ 1,  5,  6, 10, 13, 17, 20, 22]), 'B': array([ 3,  8,  9, 15, 16]), 'C': array([ 0,  2,  4,  7, 11, 12, 14])}
```

I'm looking to retrieve the key for a given number (e.g. key for 22 being 'A'), but I'm guessing it's the multi-array structure of this dict that is producing an error when using [previously posted solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary):

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Is there a straightforward way to connect the value to the key with this dict without transforming the array structure? Ultimately I'm trying to add the key of a value to a row with other associated data for export.

What I attempted based on previous answers:

```
res = dict((v, k) for k, v in mydict.items())
print(res[10])
```

I want it to print 'A' but it produces

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Have you tried using `[k for k in mydict if 22 in mydict[k]]`? The other solution you linked to doesn't seem to apply here, because you are not searching for an array but for a value *in* an array.

Comment: For the second attempt, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945473/how-to-reverse-a-dictionary-whose-values-are-lists-in-python

Comment: You get the 'ambiguity' error when doing something like `if 22==arr`. in general `==` tests on an array is tricky.  And arrays can't be dict keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a reversed dictionary you can use as a lookup (NB: this assumes you have no duplicates in your arrays - if you do they will be overwritten)

```py
from numpy import array

mydict = {'A': array([ 1,  5,  6, 10, 13, 17, 20, 22]), 
          'B': array([ 3,  8,  9, 15, 16]), 
          'C': array([ 0,  2,  4,  7, 11, 12, 14])}
rev_dct = {val: k for k, v in mydict.items() for val in v}
```

```py
print(rev_dct[22])
>>> 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it once, you may want to just do a filter:

```
from numpy import array

mydict = {'A': array([ 1,  5,  6, 10, 13, 17, 20, 22]), 'B': array([ 3,  8,  9, 15, 16]), 'C': array([ 0,  2,  4,  7, 11, 12, 14])}

res = list(filter(lambda k: 20 in mydict[k], mydict))

print(res)
```

This sets res to:

```
['A']
```

If the values only occur in one array (i.e. you only expect one key to hold a given value) then you can do a reverse/bidirectional dictionary as mentioned by oskros.